# update a file simultaneously without locking file

Tags: c++, c, perl

Problem- Multiple processes want to update a file simultaneously.I do not want to use file locking functionality as highly loaded environment a process may block for a while which i don't want. I want something like all process send data to queue or some shared place or something else and one master process will keep on taking data from there and write to the file.So that no process will get block.

One possibility using socket programming.All the processes will send data to to single port and master keep on listening this single port and store data to file.But what if master got down for few seconds.if it happen than i may write to some file based on timestamp and than later sync.But i am putting this on hold and looking for some other solution.(No data lose)

Another possibility may be tacking lock for the particular segment of the file on which the process want to write.Basically each process will write a line.I am not sure how good it will be for high loaded system.

Please suggest some solution for this problem.

Comment: Write the master such that it can't go down.

Comment: Your stated objective is to avoid locking your process during writes to the file.  Do you have any particular reason to want to use this "master" approach instead of whatever async I/O facilities your OS provides, or simply doing the writes from a background thread?

Comment: @tony- I could come up with this "master process" as only solution.Please suggest any other solution.I am using perl on linux.

Comment: @virus - "I am using perl on linux" - then why is your question tagged C and C++ as well as perl?

Comment: @tony- I am ok with the solution using C/C++. Finally i will use perl to invoke that code.

Comment: This feels horribly misguided.  You can't have it both ways, really.  If you want multiple processes writing to the same file, there is a cost to make sure there is no data corruption.  Odds are extremely high that the platform provided interfaces for this are better than whatever you come up with.

Comment: Just use some simple file-based database which takes care of nasty details. SQLite should do. Or go for a "real" database with socket access.

Answer (score 1):

Have a [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/) instance handle the writes (as you initially proposed for the socket) and have the workers connect to it and add their writes to the queue ([example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer) in many languages).

Answer (score 0):

Each process can write to own file (pid.temp) and periodically rename file (pid-0.data, pid-1.data, ...) for master process that can grab all this files.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to construct something like this. If you do not want to get processes blocked just use the `LOCK_NB` flag of perl [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html). Periodically try to `flock`. If not succeeds continue the processing and the values can stored in an array. If file locked, write the data to it from the array.

Comment: I could not understand exactly.and you are saying that "periodically try to flock", i do not want to let the process wait till it gets chance for writing.

Comment: @virus: you do not have wait. If flock returns with not success, just write the data to an array, and continue to work. Next time you may try to flock again. Of course it would be easier to see the possibilities if I knew your approach.

Comment: I am appending "name|mobile_number|country" into file and than sending a welcome message to their mobile through perl script.

Comment: @virus: ok. Then this non-breaking flock can be a proper solution as it is not vital to write the data immediately. Some buffering can work.